# What does "rows[0]" mean?

Tags: eclipse, birt

HI!  I am looking for a document that will define what the word "rows[0]" means.  this is for BIRT in the Eclipse framework.  Perhaps this is a Javascript word?  I dunno... been searching like mad and have found nothing yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*rows is a  shortcut  to dataSet.rows. Returns  the  current  data  rows  (of  type DataRow[])  for the data set associated with  this  report  item  instance.  If  this  report element has no data set, this property is undefined.*

Source: http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/ref/ROM_Scripting_SPEC.pdf

Comment: Spot on answer!  Found the definitive reference I was looking for!  You da man!

Answer (score 1):

Typically code like rows[x] is accessing an element inside an array. Any intro to programming book should be able to define that for you.

rows[0] would be accessing the *first* element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

That operation has several names depending on the language, but generally the same concept.  In Java, it's an [array access expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html#239587) in C#, it's an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691360(VS.71).aspx) or [array access operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288465(VS.71).aspx).  As with just about anything, C++ is more complicated, but basically the [] operator takes a collection of something or an array and pulls out (or assigns to) a specific numbered element in that collection or array (generally starting at 0).  So in C# ...

```
// create a list of integers
List<int> lst = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; 

// access list
int x = lst[0]; // get the first element of the list, x = 1 afterwords
x = lst[2];     // get the third element of the list, x = 3 afterwords
x = lst[4];     // get the fifth element of the list, x = 5 afterwords
x = lst[5];     // IndexOutOfBounds Exception
```